# How to run and navigate the menu at the same time with controller?

Tags: controllers, dark-souls-3, speedrun

How to use controller to navigate the menu while runing (i.e. not walking, but dashing)?

For example, in this Dark Souls 3 speed run [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=brTjImg_bKw&feature=youtu.be&t=2015) the guy simultaniously runs and navigates the menu. Note how his stamina decreased while he was in the menu - that means that he runs, not just walks. I'm sure he uses a controller, like all speed runners do.

I tried to figure out how he does it and failed. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBeco.jpg) is controller controls for DS3. Theoretically, you can press all the buttons with 3 fingers if you [claw the controller](http://i6.photobucket.com/albums/y208/THE_oldy/claw.jpg). But in practice, you have a conflict due to B button:

1. To run you must press left stick (move) and **B button (dash)** simultaniously.
2. To navigate menu you must press the menu button (entry the menu), A (accept) and **B (back)** buttons and D-pad (navigate).

Therefore, when I try it, I stop running and start walking right when I press menu button (while holding left stick and B).

Comment: If I remember correctly, you need to play on PC and have both a keyboard and a controller plugged in. You use an autorun button on the keyboard to make your character keep running then control the menu using the controller.

Comment: @SGR, interesting. What is autorun button? (or is it two buttons, rebinded to be close?) And how do you navigate menu (i.e. hold controller & press buttons on oposite ends of it) with one hand? And still - why B on controller doesn't conflict with autorun button on keyboard?

Comment: @SGR, I'm only seeing an auto-run feature for DSII. Are you sure there is one for DSIII?

Comment: In the case of Dark Souls, that's a built in feature. You use the D-pad to navigate the menu, and the sticks to move.

Comment: @Ben but OP was asking how to *dash* while navigating the menu. AFAIK, dashing and backing out of the menu have always shared the same button, at least on controllers.

Comment: Ah yes. True. That's what I get for skimming. Apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SGR suggested, it must be so called "auto-run". One can switch between walking and running by pressing a button on a keyboard. For example, at DS2 it is "X" button.

So you:
1. Run by holding Left stick + B on controller.
2. Press X on keyboard.
3. Stop holding B on controller and operate in menu.
4. Once you've done - hold B.
5. Press X on keyboard.

I'm sure this is the case, because I've found the [DS2 speed run video](https://youtu.be/-SlbZc40Jy0?t=2734) of the same guy. And DS2 shows auto run status under hp-bar.

Answer (score 1):

The best way i found of doing this was this:

1. Press start
2. Press A/X
3. Start running with B/O
4. Now you're in the menu while running.

Alternatively you can change the key binding but i found this the optimal way of doing it and with practice i became able to do it almost instantly.

The only problem i encountered was possibly going into the wrong menu, but pressing and holding B/O will take you back again while running.